# using raw SQL with Entity Framework using Store Procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm coding an Index action of the account controller whose code is:-

```
var jobPostings = context.Database.SqlQuery<EGB_JOBPOSTINGS>("EXEC EGB_GETACTIVEJOBPOSTINGS @jobID", new SqlParameter("jobID", 2));
ViewBag.JobInfo = new SelectList(jobPostings, "JobID");
return View();
```

My problem is that, I want to use the stored procedure EGB_GETACTIVEJOBPOSTINGS with Entity Framework using Raw SQL Queries as using SqlQuery. That Stored Procedure getting data from multiple tables through multiple joins. I want to ask that how can I get the result of the stored procedure while SqlQuery uses only EGB_JOBPOSTINGS class (causes a runtime exception) which is not the only object that Stored Procedure returns.

So what is the optimum way to get through? or How to solve this?

Thanks?

Comment: Can you not modify the EGB_JOBPOSTINGS class to match the data that the stored procedure returns?

Comment: Actually EGB_JOBPOSTINGS class is generated by EF through Wizard. I can't change it. Please provide me some clue. Thanks for comment.

Comment: you must edit the stored proc and use conditions outside in your application instead of using them in sql procedure.